# Pokemon Black White 2 - Ground Tiles Directory?

Tags: tiles, modding, tilesets

I opened up Pokemon Black 2 in Tinke (https://code.google.com/p/tinke/) and I'm looking for the directory that contains the ground tiles. Here's a picture showing what tiles I'm after (http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/166/e/4/pokemon_black___white_tileset_by_rossay-d3a75aj.png). I've looked for ages, but I can't find these basic tiles. Thanks :D

Comment: The link you referenced is a "custom" tileset someone made. Why are you after this? Using it in your game almost certainly is copyright infringement.

Comment: I know the link I posted is custom. I'm looking for the in game one.

Comment: I know that. Why? Reusing the game one in any of your games is copyright infringement.

Comment: My game is only for me, I won't distribute it.

Comment: I suggest using the ones you linked. I don't know if your question is on-topic for this site or not.

Comment: Those tiles are fine, but I can't find many of the basic tiles online. It's hard to printscreen rip them from the game because they are scaled/no borders/3d rotated. If I knew which folder(s) it was in, I could easily rip it. I've found some, with help from (http://pastebin.com/e5xqy9ui) but I still can't find tiles like eg. road tiles in (http://gematsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/PKMN-BW2-Teaser.jpg).

Comment: Without having ever reviewed a NDS rom or used your tinke software,  it seems like the answer is to search exhaustively.  There can't be that many folders.  Search them all until you find what you want.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about searching for assets within a static game rom.

Comment: Where to find art resources is explicitly off-topic for this site, as per the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Some notes from the comments:

- Using Nintendo's official art work (ripping it and using it) is definitely a **violation of copyright.** (Your response was you're only using it for yourself.)
- Questions about "help me rip ... from game ..." are probably off-topic for this site.

What I really recommend, like [your link](http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/166/e/4/pokemon_black___white_tileset_by_rossay-d3a75aj.png), is to use custom tiles which other people made which are similar to what you want.

The Google image search for `tiles similar to pokemon black white` looks [quite fruitful](https://www.google.com/search?q=pokemon+black+white+tiles&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=trR3U_naEdKxyASckILgCw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1280&bih=923#q=tiles+similar+to+pokemon+black+white&tbm=isch).